# Android: Error when pressing back button, even after finishing the previous activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am getting nullpointer exception somewhere near the line where i am using getIntent.getextra().

This is the error log:

```
 04-25 14:19:43.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10031): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 04-25 14:19:43.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10031): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{com.example.attendence/com.example.attendence.UserPage}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
 04-25 14:19:43.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10031):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
 04-25 14:19:43.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10031):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
 04-25 14:19:43.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10031):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 04-25 14:19:43.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10031):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
 04-25 14:19:43.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10031):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 04-25 14:19:43.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10031):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
 04-25 14:19:43.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10031):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
 04-25 14:19:43.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10031):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 04-25 14:19:43.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10031):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 04-25 14:19:43.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10031):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
 04-25 14:19:43.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10031):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
 04-25 14:19:43.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10031):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 04-25 14:19:43.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10031): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 04-25 14:19:43.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10031):   at com.example.attendence.UserPage.onCreate(UserPage.java:52)
 04-25 14:19:43.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10031):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 04-25 14:19:43.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10031):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
 04-25 14:19:43.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10031):   ... 11 more
```

This is the code iam using to call the second activity(which is called UserPage) in my first activity:

```
            startActivity(new Intent(HelloUser.this, UserPage.class));
            intent= new Intent(HelloUser.this, UserPage.class);
            intent.putExtra("title11", "p");
            intent.putExtra("name", et.getText().toString().trim());
            startActivity(intent); 
            finish();
```

as you can see i am calling finish() so the back button should not work in next activity.

This is the second activity which is called Userpage, in which the error is coming:

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.userpage);

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);

    title11= (String)getIntent().getStringExtra("title11");
    name= (String)getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    if(title11.equals("new"))
    {
        title11=null;
        UserPage.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserPage.this);
                builder.setTitle("Welcome");
                builder.setMessage("Hello "+name)  
                       .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           }
                       });                     
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();               
            }
        });
    }
    t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.titlename);
    t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.gname);
    t1.setText(name);
    t2.getBackground().setAlpha(55);

    t2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           startActivity(new Intent(UserPage.this, CreateGroup.class));
       }
    });

}
}
```

Error is coming on the line " if(title11.equals("new"))" when i press back button.

Comment: try this if (title11 == null) { Log.w("", "title11 is null"); }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
startActivity(new Intent(HelloUser.this, UserPage.class));
            intent= new Intent(HelloUser.this, UserPage.class);
            intent.putExtra("title11", "p");
            intent.putExtra("name", et.getText().toString().trim());
            startActivity(intent); 
            finish();
```

You're starting the activity two times, so the first one started can't find `title11`. Try this instead :

```
 intent= new Intent(HelloUser.this, UserPage.class);
                intent.putExtra("title11", "p");
                intent.putExtra("name", et.getText().toString().trim());
                startActivity(intent); 
                finish();
```

Comment: Yes that worked, actually i saw that double call before i came across the error, and i thought "what difference would that make" :D

Answer (score 0):

You're starting the activity 2 times. The `NullPointerException` is raised by the first started activity, because `title11` isn't set for that Activity's `Intent`.

Also, if the only purpose of that finish is making sure a HelloUser activity never enters the "Back button history", it's a better practice to set `android:noHistory="true"` for that Activity in your manifest instead of your current implementation.